# Identifying reverse flow of steps in SQL, for a particular entity

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help in constructing a logic for the below problem:

In a table, there are ticket numbers and certain sequence of steps associated with them.

For a given ticket number, the ***forward*** flow of steps is for e.g.

A --> B --> C --> D

(OR)

A --> B --> D etc.

I need to identify all the ticket numbers with ***reverse*** flow, for e.g:

A --> B --> A

(OR)

A --> B --> C --> B

View Table image for example:
[image: View Table image for example]

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Without another column in the table that specify the correct order of the rows, what you are asking for is impossible, since rows in a database table have no inherent order - tables are unordered sets of records.

Comment: or can we reduce the problem to looking for ticket numbers that have more than one occurrence of the same step in their unordered set of steps? if we had an ordinal column, then the basic principle would use the alphabetical order of the steps in the form "is there any leading record on the same ticket where `Steps` is smaller (or equal?)"

Answer (score 0):

Independant of the actual order (the *workflow*) it is easy to check, whether a step re-occurs within one workflow.

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(TicketNumber INT,Steps VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES(1,'A'),(1,'B'),(1,'C'),(1,'D')
                              ,(2,'A'),(2,'B'),(2,'A')
                              ,(3,'A'),(3,'B'),(3,'C'),(3,'A');

SELECT TicketNumber,Steps 
FROM @mockupTable
GROUP BY TicketNumber,Steps
HAVING COUNT(Steps)>1;
```

The result:

```
TicketNumber    Steps
2               A
3               A
```

This will return any case of repeated occurances of one step within one TicketNumber